# On the value of the structure of the issue

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield, viewdidappear, pass-data

## When using input structures to create multiple save arrays, do not display the array in a custom cell.

The following is the initialization settings

```
struct LearnList {
    var Title:String
    var Des:String

    init (Title:String,Des:String){
        self.Title = Title
        self.Des = Des
    }
}
```

The following is the method code after clicking Complete

```
 @IBAction func Complete(_ sender: Any) {

    if (InputTitleTextField.text != nil),
        (InputDesTextField.text != nil)
{
    let  LearnString = LearnList(Title: InputTitleTextField.text!, Des:  InputDesTextField.text!)
    LearnArray.append(InfoString)
    self.InputTitleTextField.text = ""
    self.InputDesTextField.text = ""
}
```

}

Where should I insert the following code in the main ViewController?

```
（override） func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    LearnTableView.reloadData()
}
```

**What should be read in this area?**

My learning reference link:

[How To Create A To Do List App In Xcode 8 (Swift 3.0)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrCqXmHenJY&list=PLSQeBzOrTtlHgEkkPPxZp6j6c9yTMysqr&t=5s&index=1)

My question on programming in China，（there is still no answer）:

> [UITextField:用户输入append方法错误以及回答里的新问题无法传值的问题](https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000013136287)

The first question in detail the process of inquiry, later found their own programs to show the fixed characters, but the code was not saved, try to modify their own user input failed.

Comment: After Complete Button hit the data is not being updated in the array?

Comment: I try to break at append point, think it is not not to save the data.
But prompt (lldb) Complete
error: 'Complete' is not a valid command.
error: Unrecognized command 'Complete'.
But I have done IBAction and IBOutlet.

Comment: Aside bar note: for `LearnList`, you don't have to implement this `init` since Swift structures have *member wise initializer*.

Comment: Ah, I see a tutorial is no init, but some have
Well, I see a tutorial is no init, but some open-source todo demo there

Answer (score 0):

Add the `reloadData()` to the end of your `Complete()` not in the `viewDidAppear()`